# How do I enable GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK mask in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gtk, glade

I'm trying to get a motion-notify-event working to drag images in a GTK Haskell project and to get a WidgetMotionNotifyEventCallback signal the documentation says that I need to enable a mask, but I can't find how to do that or I'm misunderstanding what that means.

[Documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.37/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html)
"To receive this signal, the Window associated to the widget needs to enable the GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK mask."

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`widgetAddEvents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.37/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html#v:widgetAddEvents), with a list containing [`EventMaskPointerMotionMask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gdk-3.0.26/docs/GI-Gdk-Flags.html#t:EventMask).